# Where to put utility (not administration) stored procedures in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up a central CLR stored procedure / function respository library for internal stored procs in other databases to use?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22460/setting-up-a-central-clr-stored-procedure-function-respository-library-for-int)

I have some simple user-defined functions for string manipulations. Most of them are actually CLR functions but not all of them are. I use them from multiple databases on the same server. What is the proper place to put these?

I've been placing them in the master DB so far. Is that a bad idea? If so, why? Is it standard practice to have a utility database that has no data but only progammability objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would put them in a Utility database.

Putting stuff in the master database is something to avoid as it stores information related to the system configuration.  If there is a problem with the master database, your SQL Server will go down.  It's probably ok to put normal stored procedures used for server level troubleshooting like sp_WhoIsActive but I would never put a CLR based procedure in there.

Comment: i call my utility database `DBA`

Comment: I call mine `Utility`.